# Adding @booktitle to BibLaTeX reference for @misc reference entries

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, overleaf, mendeley

I'm using Overleaf and trying to use the built-in feature to load references from Mendeley.

However, there is a bug where Web Page's accessed dates do not load into the Bibliography, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518912/dateaccessed-missing-when-importing-with-mendeley).

In this thread, the workaround by @Aslak Todal is:

> One of the fields that are provided is "publications", which is
> transferred to the .bib file as @booktitle. Since most webpages don't
> have book titles, this can be exploited by copy-pasting the date
> accessed into the "publications" field and using BibLaTeX-settings
> that displays the @booktitle field for @misc entries.

In Mendeley I have included the accessed date in "publications", but I'm not sure how to modify the BibLaTeX settings to display @booktitle for @misc entries.

Please could someone give an example on how I would modify this formatting so that I can properly cite web pages?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you contacted Mendeley's helpdesk? They are the primary go-to station for Mendeley-related issues.

Comment: I thinks it's a *mistake* to try and define a `booktitle` field for entries of type `@misc`.

Comment: In the post I linked to this workaround is proposed by Overleaf's support due to the bug mentioned. I agree it's not ideal.

Answer (score 5):

`biblatex` does not use the `booktitle` field for `@misc` entries and I don't think it makes sense semantically to force `biblatex` to do so.

Frankly, I believe that Mendeley should just properly write the URL access date into the `urldate` field when it exports `.bib` files for `biblatex`. A software that claims to be compatible with `biblatex` should not require extremely unusual workarounds like the one suggested in the quote.

You should definitely complain to the Mendeley people. You may also want to consider using a software that properly supports `biblatex` in its `.bib` export feature.

If you must stick with Mendeley and can only bring it to export to the access date to the `booktitle` field, you can try to remap `booktitle` to `urldate` for `@misc` entries.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{misc}
      \step[fieldsource=booktitle,   fieldtarget=urldate]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{elk,
  author    = {Anne Elk},
  title     = {A Theory on Brontosauruses},
  year      = {1972},
  url       = {https://example.edu/~elk/bronto.pdf},
  booktitle = {2021-01-07},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{elk}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Elk, Anne (1972). A Theory on Brontosauruses. url: https://example.edu/~elk/bronto.pdf (visited on 07/01/2021).]

Comment: Thanks for this detailed reply! I agree it's not ideal and Mendeley and Overleaf need to work to fix this issue.

Comment: @OscarVanL If I understand correctly what is going on here, I don't think Overleaf can do any better here. This appears to be completely on Mendeley, since they are the ones exporting the `.bib` file. I have seen several complaints about Mendeley and its `.bib` export on this site, and I always encourage users with such issues to complain to Mendeley, but I don't know if people report the issues to the Mendeley developers and if the developers care about it. ...

Comment: ... From what I have heard [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/) (an open source alternative to Mendeley) usually gives better results in its `.bib` export especially with the [Better BibTeX plugin](https://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/). I think Zotero also integrates with Overleaf to some degree, so maybe that would be an alternative. (But I use neither Overleaf nor Zotero or Mendeley productively, so this is mostly hearsay.) The Zotero developers are also *very* responsive on GitHub and their support forum.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Open source is better :)